# Concat operation returns empty list

Tags: haskell, concatenation

```
module Sample where

lastPeg = 15
leftCol  = [1, 2, 4, 7 , 11]
rightCol = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
rowData = []

makeRowData :: Integer-> Integer-> [Integer] 
makeRowData row pos = 
      if (pos <= lastPeg) then
        if (pos >= leftCol !! (fromIntegral row-1)) &&
           (pos <= rightCol !! (fromIntegral row-1)) then
          do
            rowData ++ [row]
            makeRowData row (pos + 1)
        else
          makeRowData (row+1) (pos)
      else
        rowData
```

What I am essentially trying to do is make a triangle-shaped vector
represented as a single vector.  Given a position within the triangle
I want to return the row containing that position.

For example:
`rowData [6]  = 4`  (Represented as the 7th position in the triangle)

desired result: rowData = `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`

actual  result: rowData = `[]`

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you may be assuming that variables in Haskell are immutable. This is not the case: an expression such as `rowData ++ [row]` does not change `rowData`, but rather returns a new list which is the concatenation of `rowData` and `[row]`. Similarly `do` blocks don’t necessarily run each line within them one by one. I suspect you may need to find a different approach to implement this successfully in Haskell.

Comment: Anyway, here’s a simple solution for your problem: `rowData = (!!) $ [1..] >>= join replicate` (note that you will need to import `Control.Monad` for this). For instance, `rowData 6` yields 4 as required.

Comment: What @bradrn means is, Haskell variables are not _mutable_. They are, indeed, immutable, i.e. they can not be modified.

Comment: Your solution works and is a lot more elegant.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Oops, that is indeed what I meant! Thanks for the correction!

Comment: in Haskell, `rowData [6]` is written `rowData !! 6`, with lists (as here), and  `rowData ! 6` with arrays. `[1..] >>= join replicate` is simpler (not *shorter*) written as `[i | i <- [1..], _ <- replicate i i]` or just `[i | i <- [1..], _ <- [1..i]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your central issue is in this part of the code:

```
do
  rowData ++ [row]
  makeRowData row (pos + 1)
```

I wonder if someone explained the operator `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` to you as “appends a list to another list”, giving you the impression that an expression like `xs ++ ys` *modifies* `xs`. The first problem is that this isn’t the case; in reality this operator returns a *new* list consisting of the two inputs concatenated together, e.g. in GHCi:

```
> xs = [1, 2, 3]
> ys = [4, 5]

> xs ++ ys       -- Append the lists.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

> xs             -- The original lists aren’t modified.
[1, 2, 3]

> ys
[4, 5]
```

The second problem is that the `do` block here has misled you: it’s operating on *lists*, so it doesn’t do the sequencing like `IO` that you seem to expect. `do` notation can be used with lists because the list type has an instance of the `Monad` typeclass, but instead of sequencing like `IO`, the list `Monad` instance does *iteration*, exactly like a list comprehension.

A full tutorial on monads and `do` notation is beyond the scope of this answer, but for example, all of these are equivalent:

```
-- List comprehension:
[x * y | x <- [2, 3], y <- [3, 5]]

-- Equivalent ‘do’ notation:
do { x <- [2, 3]; y <- [3, 5]; pure (x * y) }

-- Desugared ‘do’ notation:
[2, 3] >>= (\ x -> [3, 5] >>= (\ y -> pure (x * y)))

-- Instances of ‘Monad’ & ‘Applicative’ for lists:
concatMap (\ x -> concatMap (\ y -> [x * y]) [3, 5]) [2, 3]

-- Result of all of the above:
[6, 10, 9, 15]
```

So what your `do` block is doing is iterating over the list `rowData ++ [row]`, which is *always* the single element `row`, because `rowData` is *always* the empty list `[]`, by its definition. `=` means equal! In that single “loop” iteration, there’s a recursive call to `makeRowData`, and these calls continue, counting up with the `pos` parameter until it reaches `lastPeg`, at which point the function returns `rowData`, which is, again, just another name for `[]`.

There are simpler and more idiomatic ways to solve the problem, but for the sake of learning, if you want to make as small a modification as possible and keep essentially this same explicit recursive structure, then the general principle of the solution is this:

- Add a helper function with an “accumulator” parameter that keeps track of your intermediate state
- Call this function from `makeRowData` with the initial state
- If necessary, perform some final processing on the result before returning it from `makeRowData`

For example:

```
makeRowData :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] 
makeRowData initialRow initialPos

  -- Start the “loop” with an initial ‘rowData’ of ‘[]’.
  = makeRowDataHelper [] initialRow initialPos

makeRowDataHelper :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
makeRowDataHelper rowData row pos =
  if (pos <= lastPeg) then
    if (pos >= leftCol !! (fromIntegral row-1)) &&
       (pos <= rightCol !! (fromIntegral row-1)) then
        -- To “modify” the state for the next iteration,
        -- recursively call ‘go’ with different values.
        makeRowDataHelper (rowData ++ [row]) row (pos + 1)
    else
      makeRowDataHelper rowData (row+1) (pos)
  else
    -- To exit the iteration, just return a value.
    rowData
```

I haven’t tested whether your logic is actually correct here, but at least this should help you get unstuck.

Beyond that, there are also a few performance and style improvements you could make here:

- Appending linked lists with `++` is slow; each iteration of `go` above, `++` must traverse the entire left hand side to construct its result, and that argument grows with each recursive call, so this function ends up taking quadratic time O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the length of the input. That doesn’t matter so much for small lists like this, but quickly becomes too inefficient to use with larger inputs.

  A common way to solve this is to instead *prepend* elements to the accumulator parameter using the “cons” operator (`element : list`) in reverse order instead of *appending* them (`list ++ [element]`), then `reverse` the result afterward if necessary, since this is only linear O(n).
- Instead of `if … then … else …` at the top level of a definition, it’s generally considered more idiomatic to use *guards*, for example:

  ```
  go rowData row pos

    | pos > lastPeg
    = rowData

    | pos >= leftCol !! (fromIntegral row-1)
    , pos <= rightCol !! (fromIntegral row-1)
    = …

    | otherwise
    = …
  ```
- You’re repeatedly using `!!` on lists, which also takes linear time O(n) in the value of the index to traverse the list. Consider using a different data structure, such as `Data.Array` or `Data.Vector` which have constant-time O(1) indexing, or a different algorithm that doesn’t require random-access indexing into the lists. (E.g. look into the `replicate` function.)